# 2 functions which are not conjugate

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

We know that if $f,g : X \to X$ are two homeomorphisms then they are conjugate if we could find a homeomorphism say $h:X \to X$ which satisfies $hf=gh$.

Now consider the following functions:
\begin{align}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x  & x<\frac{1}{2} \\
-2x+2 & x \geq\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x & x<\frac{1}{2} \\
2x-1 & x \geq \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I want to show that they are not conjugate.

My idea is to show Fix point set of $f$ is not invariant under $h$.(We know under a conjugacy between to maps $h(Fix(f))= Fix(g)$ ) What I need to do is to find a homeomorphism $h$ which satisfies $hf=gh$ but I have problem finding this:

For $x<\frac{1}{2}$
\begin{align}
h(f(x))=g(h(x)) \Rightarrow h(2x)=2h(x)
\end{align}
For $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$
\begin{align}
h(f(x))=g(h(x)) \Rightarrow h(-2x+2)=2h(x)-1
\end{align}
I don't know how to precede to find such a $h$? could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ were conjugate then $g=h\circ f \circ h^{-1}$ for some *homeomorphism* $h:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. But $h,f,$ and $h^{-1}$ are continuous at $x=1/2$ which would imply $g$ is continuous at $x=1/2$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint (Assuming $X=\mathbb{T}^1$):** Instead of trying to solve a functional equation it might be easier to solve an algebraic equation, say one given by induced maps on fundamental groups. What are the degrees? (Note that your definition of conjugacy is correct, but the maps are not invertible.)

Here is a humble graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4k71bg3zot